# OpenCV Remapping crops my Landscape Image

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, distortion, remap

I just started with the Mono Camera Calibration in OpenCV.
Thereby I use the sample code from 
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html
which is handy and nicely written.

Now the problem is that I use landscape and portrait images for the input. These images are all 1600x1200 pixels and display a chessboard, however in some of these images the view is rotated 90 degrees. Now the code goes like this:

```
        view = imread(s.imageList[i], 1);
        if(view.empty())
            continue;

        remap(view, rview, map1, map2, INTER_LINEAR);
        imshow("Image View", rview);
        imwrite(s.imageList[i], rview);
```

The remapping(getting rid of distortions) is successfull, but the image which is saved is cropped for the landscape images. That means that the algorithm somehow tries to put the undistorted image in a portrait shape resulting in this:
http://picload.org/view/lccorri/img_0197.jpg.html

Anybody got some input why that is?

Comment: By `rotated 90 degrees` do you mean that you have images of 1200x1600px? Or that your rotated the camera by 90° and still have images of 1600x1200px?

Comment: i meant i rotated the camera by 90° and therefore have images of 1200x1600px (width x height).

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the computation of the rectifymaps:

```
    initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, Mat(), getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, Size(1600,1600), 1, Size(1600,1600), 0),
        Size(1600,1600), CV_16SC2, map1, map2);
```

Here I had a mistake, for the size of the image I now set Size(1600,1600), which fixed the size to 1600 x 1600. Now it doesnt matter if the image is rotated (1200x1600) it will not be cropped. For now I am satisfied, of course its not the best solution.